# "going to die" vs "to die"

Tags: infinitives, future-tense

My SO from Japan contemplates two phrases:

1. "We are going to die eventually."
2. "We are to die eventually."

Why does sentence 1. sound more correct?
Is sentence 2. correct at all?

Comment: Both are possible, but #1 is definitely more common / everyday; #2 is more ... I don't know, British and existential?

Comment: Heh, yeah #2 does sound more British.
That actually answers my question. Thanks!

Comment: *To be + infinitive* implies obligation; e.g. *all essays are to be submitted by Thursday.* Nevertheless, the construction feels off in your example.

Answer (score 1):

Both are correct but mean different things.

*Be + infinitive X* means "destined to X" - usually in the sense that someone has planned, programmed, or commanded X to happen.

*Going to X* = *will X*.  Usually this is part of the English future tense, which simply describes an action in the future, but doesn't automatically have the planning or "control of destiny" implication of *be to X* (this is different from *will* being used to issue requests which is also possible).

So:

> We are going to die eventually = We will die eventually - e.g. of natural causes or of whatever is happening currently.  There is no implication that someone/something is planning it.
>
> We are to die eventually = Someone/something has planned our death and it will happen eventually.

Answer (score 0):

The first sounds more natural, because the phrase `going to` specifically refers to the future, whereas the second does not:

> Going to is not a tense. It is a special structure that we use to talk
>   about the future. The structure of "going to" is: **subject   +   be  +   going   +   to-infinitive**

```
SUBJECT   BE    NOT    GOING    TO-INFINITIVE    
I         am           going    to buy           a new car.
I         'm           going    to go            swimming.
He        is    not    going    to take          the exam.
It        is    n't    going    to rain.     
Are       you          going    to paint         the house?
```

https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/verbs-m_going-to.htm

Comment: and 'eventually' doesn't imply the future???

Answer (score 0):

*Going to die* suggests that the subject will die in the future. In difference, *to die* in that context suggests that it is the subject's function and purpose to die.

Think of it this way: *we are* in isolation could be redefined as *we exist*. Then, simply substitute the verb: *we exist to die*. You can see the implication of function here.

Comment: +1, I have same interpretation as you. Minor comment: I think italics not fixed-width font would be easier to read for the quotes.